# Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged

Tags: python

Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

```
def front_back(str):
  if len(str) <= 1:
   return str

  elif len(str) = 2:
   return str[1] + str[0]

  elif len(str) > 2:
   return str[len(str)-1] + str[1, len(str)-1] + str[0]
```

which is wrong?

Comment: Are you asking us whether this is wrong, or do you know it's wrong and want to know why?

Comment: You're missing a comparison in the middle condition.  You need `len(str) == 2`, but you supplied an assignment.

Comment: @Prune Well, the code is there, but it's lacking a description of the problem.

Comment: `str` is a python class name, in general you should avoid using those for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Your cases are all correct, just the syntax on your slice is off. Instead of `str[1, len(str)-1]` use `str[1:len(str)-1]`

In Python, the `=` sign means assignment, not equality. In the first `elif` block, you should use `==`, the symbol for an equality test instead.

Also 'str' is a builtin class. Adhering to best practices, please do not use it as a variable. Consider 'string' or 'text'

See sample output below:

```
>>> def swap_fl(string):
...     if len(string) <= 1:
...             return string
...     elif len(string) == 2:
...             return string[::-1]
...     else:
...             return string[len(string)-1] + string[1:len(string)-1] + string[0]
...
>>> swap_fl('')
''
>>> swap_fl('b')
'b'
>>> swap_fl('at')
'ta'
>>> swap_fl('ate')
'eta'
```